# Visual Studio 2017 cMake diagram view

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2017, diagram

Recently I have opened a .sln project in VS 2017 and I noticed that I can view diagram of all classes - its 1st time I ever noticed it and I'm quite "wow this is epic".

I now have a cMake based project that I open via > open Folder > cmake root folder. Even tho it opens/ compiles I don't see any view diagram option. Does any1 know how to enable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMake should generate a Visual Studio solution (sln). You need to run CMake and then open the generated solution which will be put in your build folder. You will have to view/edit your CMakeSettings.json to see where your build folder is when opening a CMake project in Visual Studio. Alternatively just run CMake from the command line to get the solution file.

Comment: Interesting, so I can use cmake directly in 2017 to run project, but if I want to view diagram I have to go CMakeBuild>id>build>x64_Debug>project.sln - open that  and then I can see diagram view?

Comment: @Dariusz, that's right, although you can configure where that folder lives.

Comment: *CMake should generate a Visual Studio solution* - Note that starting with Visual Studio 2017 [you can open CMake projects directly in Visual Studio](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/10/05/cmake-support-in-visual-studio/) without manually running CMake first. This is probably what OP did here. This will currently still run CMake in the background, you just don't see it.

Comment: @ComicSansMS, that's why I mentioned CMakeSettings.json

Comment: Hey, since some time has passed and vs has updated a little this seems to no longer work? I don't see any .sln files anymore in debug folders... Any hints what to do now? @keith

Comment: @Dariusz, are you running cmake form the command line and telling it to use the Visual Studio generator? That should always work. I usually create a powershell file to do it :-)

Comment: Nope, I just go to VS - file->open->cMakeProject. Can you share any examples or hints how to do it ? I tried cmakeGUi to convert my cmake project to VS solution but that did not work either :- (. So weird that class diagram is not natively supported in vs.

Comment: @Dariusz, I am suggesting you use the command line to invoke cmake to convert your CMakeLists.txt into a VS project.